Source of applicationDidBecomeActive: user vs. bug?
I have an Objective-C app that sometimes takes over focus without the user actively switching to it. I want to track when this happens, so I can have a dump and analyze why this happens.
For this reason, I wanted to see if when I get applicationDidBecomeActive I can distinguish when it happened because of the user (clicked on app in dock, cmd+tabbed to it, etc.) vs. when it happened because my app is broken (e.g. crashed and restarted).
Obviously, I don't want to track ALL user input across the whole system.
I'm developing for MacOS.
Is there a way to do that?
